# Initializing IEnumerable C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to initialize an IEnumerable, but I am getting the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.KeyValuePair>' .

with code

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, String>> users;

if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator"))
{
    users = _systemUserCommand.LookupUsersInRole(null, query)
        .Select(s => new { s.SystemUserId, Text = string.Format("{0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName) });
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `Select` projection isn't returning `KeyValuePair<>`

Comment: ultimately, a `new { s.SystemUserId, Text = string.something }` is **not** a `KeyValuePair<Guid,string>` - it isn't enough to be "kinda similar"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, String>>`, don't you mean `Dictionary<Guid, String>`?

And you can't insert an anonymous type in a list of a specified type, you need to create a `new KeyValuePair`
*(Or just do a `.ToDictionary()` if you are working with it)*

---

Assuming you are using the Dictionary approach:

```
Dictionary<Guid, string> users;
users = _systemUserCommand.LookupUsersInRole(null, query)
            .ToDictionary(
                s => s.SystemUserId,
                s => string.Format("{0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName)
            );
```

---

Assuming you are using the IEnumerable approach:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid, String>> users;
users = _systemUserCommand.LookupUsersInRole(null, query)
            .Select(s =>new KeyValuePair<Guid, String>(
                s.SystemUserId,
                string.Format("{0} {1}", s.FirstName, s.LastName)
            ));
```

Comment: I *like* the `ToDictionary` approach here - slight caveat: it will explode if there are duplicate folks with the same guid, where-as `Select` won't

Comment: Can you show me a sample?  I'm getting `invalid initializer member declarator` now for `s.SystemUserId` and `Text`

Comment: Is there a way to still have `Text = string.format...`?  I'm returning Json so in the View I need to be able to get the Id and name.

Comment: @Andrew Not currently possible. Your enumerable can hold only one Guid + one string. There is no `Text` field.  
Do you mean that the `String` part will have __all__ the data you need? If that's the case, you can json-serialize all your data

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I need to json serialize all the data.